# ffmpeg for flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, video-editing

I need to develop a video editor in flash, which can crop videos, add audio, etc. I found ffmpeg library for the purpose but its in c/c++. I don't know how can I use in as3. Can anyone help me regarding the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fffmpeg library with flash, this tut may help you to start your project :)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6N7eN9wvAGQ&list=LLxsjQrUrxiJM8t2HQfgLX7Q